# Rotating plane but not the object

Tags: c++, 3d, rotation, directx-11

As the title says, how do you rotate the plane but not the object. I'd like the car I have in my program to accelerate in the x direction when I turn. So I'd like to turn the plane. That way I can press forward and go in the direction the car is pointing after I rotate the car.

```
XMMATRIX carTranslation = XMMatrixTranslation(mCarTranslation.x, mCarTranslation.y, mCarTranslation.z);
XMMATRIX carScale = XMMatrixScaling(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
XMMATRIX carRotate = XMMatrixRotationY(carRotation.y);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mCarWorld, carRotate*carTranslation*carScale);
```

I know that if you put the carRotate before everything else it rotates just the car. And if I put it after it rotates just the plane. I'd like to rotate the plane and not the object.

Comment: You can define two world matrix, one for your car and another for your plane, then transform and draw them separately.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to work on one plane and rotate the car. Then find the slope velocity with cos and sin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cosine and sine to find a slope velocity. I didn't make another matrix and I just rotated the car normally.

```
mCarTranslation.x += (cos(carRotation.y)*v);
mCarTranslation.z += -(sin(carRotation.y)*v);
```